# How use reflection to load dependency assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to load **Assembly1.dll** and print out all its methods:

```
Assembly assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFile("c:\temp\Assembly1.dll");
foreach (Type type in assembly1.GetExportedTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());

    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods())
    {
        Console.Write($"    {(methodInfo.IsStatic ? "static" : "")} {methodInfo.ReturnType} {methodInfo.Name} (");
        ParameterInfo[] aParams = methodInfo.GetParameters();

        for (int i = 0; i < aParams.Length; i++)
        {
            ParameterInfo param = aParams[i];

            if (i > 0)
                Console.Write(", ");

            Console.Write($"{ (param.ParameterType.IsByRef && param.IsOut ? "out" : "") } { (param.ParameterType.IsByRef && !param.IsOut ? "ref" : "") } {param.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

When the last "Consol.Write" runs, it threw the following exception:

```cs
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

I know why, because some of the methods in **Assembly1.dll** has some parameters, and the types of these parameters are defined in **Assembly2.dll**.

So, how do I solve this problem? I mean, how do I load both assemblies?

Comment: I think you should move all the dependencies of Assembly1 in the same folder as Assembly1 and then load all the dlls in that folder instead of only Assembly1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please correct my code to show me how to load both assemblies? I tried and it didn't work...

Comment: Never use LoadFile, use LoadFrom to give the CLR a shot at finding the dependent dlls.

Comment: Add this to the top of your code:
Assembly.LoadFile("c:\temp\Assembly2.dll");

Comment: Do you know the file location of the Assembly2 that it is talking about?